# PHP && Short-circuit Evaluation Operator

Tags: php, short-circuiting

In JavaScript, I can do:

```
console.log( 'a' || 'b' ); // Prints 'a'
```

In PHP, the equivalent is:

```
echo 'a' ?: 'b'; // Prints 'a'
```

In JavaScript:

```
console.log( 'a' && 'b' ); // Prints 'b'
```

**My question is, what is the PHP equivalent of JavaScript's 'a' && 'b'?**

If I do the following in PHP:

```
echo 'a' && 'b'; // Prints 1
```

As you can see, it type casts to boolean 1 (true).

What is the PHP operator that will get me the actual values, like JavaScript's &&?

P.S. I know about ternary statements, please don't suggest that.

Comment: above does't work in PHP if you don't want ternary then there is no option here.

Comment: Your posted JavaScript is abusing JavaScript's type-juggling functionality and should not be used in production code because "logically" boolean operators should evaluate to boolean values - the fact that JavaScript carries the original value while pretending it's a boolean value is a quirk that's unique to JavaScript and is largely non-existent in other languages.

Comment: Logical operation in PHP always return boolean value, you can't have the same behavior in PHP with this expression, you have to do it by code, using `if` statement or `ternary` https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php#77411

Answer (score 1):

`&&` is a logical operator, and it evaluates to `true | false`. There is a slightly different operator in PHP named **null coalesce operator**. It is denoted `??`. It evaluates whether the first operand is `null`. If it is `null`, the result is the second operand of the statement.

```
$variable = 'String';
return $variable ?? 'default'; // results in 'String'

$variable = null;
return $variable ?? 'default'; // results in 'default'
```

More on the operator: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary

Comment: This one is close, but it only works with NULL. Is there a similar operator in PHP that will work with ALL falsy values? For example, -1, "", etc.